# Module not found - while adding a component in app.js

Tags: react-native

**I am using React Native. Below is my code in app.js.**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Header from './components/Header';

export default function App() { 
    return (
        <View>
        </View>
    );
}
```

**I made another directory in root and added another js file which is Header.js. It contains below code.**

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default function Header() {
    return (    
        <View>
        </View>
    );
}
```

**I got an error message below.**

> The development server returned response error code: 500
>
> The module `./components/Header` could not be found

[image]

**Directory Structure**

[image]

Please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: can you check this https://snack.expo.io/SJ1cnsipr i hhgot no error

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
const Header = () => {
    return (    
        <View>
        </View>
    );
}

export default Header
```

Don't just reload an app, restart packager also.

Answer (score 0):

Please correct your functional header component as:

```
const Header = () => {
return(
<View>.............</View>
)}

export default Header
```

And run **react-native start** and **react-native run-android**

Answer (score 0):

Replace Header component to this:-

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

const Header = ({props}) => {  // you can also access props like this 
return (    
    <View>
    </View>
);
}
```